# Odd results from Google Reverse Geocode API

Tags: api, reverse, geocode

Recently I've been occasionally receiving odd results from the Google Reverse Geocode API.
For example when looking up the address for coordinates 43.2379396 -72.44746565 the result I get is:

```
6HQ3+52 Springfield, VT, USA
```

In another case looking up 43.703563 -72.209753 results with:

```
PQ3R+C3 Hanover, NH, USA
```

Does anyone know what the initial 7 bytes of the returned address symbolize?  When I receive this type of result it's always 4 bytes of alphanumeric data followed by a plus sign then 2 more alphanumeric bytes.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional research I found that these are Plus Code addresses, a relatively new feature in Google Maps.  These are used for places that don't have a street address.  These seem to have some similarities to "what 3 words" addresses.